# If “Mensch” is masculine, why is it “ein ehrlicher Mensch”?

Tags: gender, article

*Mensch* is masculine, but I saw *ein ehrlicher Mensch* today.
I have seen similar cases, but don’t understand why one must use *ein.*

Comment: Because it is masculine ;)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_articles#The_Indefinite_Article

Comment: "Ein" is the masculine indefinite article in the nominative ("der" is the definite article).

Comment: It would help if you would tell what you had expected instead.

Comment: You are probably confused because of the [two different inflections types of adjectives, articles and similar in German](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/index.html?MenuId=Word313&lang=en).

Comment: It depends on what one wants to say, for certain contexts "der ehrliche Mensch" is possible, too. As already remarked above: showcase what you think it should be instead (and if possible the context, too), and you will likely receive some revealing answers.

Answer (score 2):

to suggest your expected article: "der Mensch", instead of "ein Mensch".
I can summarize the above comments for you:
neither "der Mensch" nor "ein Mensch" is wrong. As "der" is the definite masculine it refers to a specific individual human (or in this case it can mean humanity as well but let's forget about that). "ein" refers to one but any human.

As I already mentioned your case is special because of the overladed meaning of "Mensch".
So let's take it by "Person":
The person, who ate my sandwich, will pay for that sin! - "Die Person" - because it is not any person but one special person.
I need a person to hunt the sandwich-thief down. - "Eine Person" - because any person is sufficient.